# limit of an expression including BesselK function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

i want to calculate the limit of the following expression when 'w' tend to zero. I have used the Limit function, it takes a lot of time for running without any result. could you please help me how to do that?
Thanks in advance

```
  Limit[1 - ((BesselK[m, w]^2)/(BesselK[m - 1, w]*BesselK[m + 1, w])), w -> 0];
```

p.s: I know the answer is 1/m, but I want to show this.

Comment: The limit is given by $\frac{1}{m}, \text{for}\; m\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @yarchik Thanks for your response. I know that. but I want to show this

Comment: With suitable assumptions we can get this for `m>1`. `In[334]:= ll = 
 Limit[1 - BesselK[m, w]^2/(BesselK[-1 + m, w] BesselK[1 + m, w]), 
  w -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", Assumptions -> m > 1]

Out[334]= 1 - Gamma[m]^2/(Gamma[-1 + m] Gamma[1 + m])

In[335]:= Simplify[FunctionExpand[ll, Assumptions -> m > 1]]

Out[335]= 1/m`

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

This limit is hard for m Integer...

The following takes about 30 secs to evaluate:

```
Limit[Limit[Normal[Series[1 - ((BesselK[m, w]^2)/(BesselK[m - 1, w]*
       BesselK[m + 1, w])), {w, 0, 0}]] /. m -> m - e, w -> 0, 
Direction -> "FromAbove"], e -> 0] // FullSimplify
```

and gives 1/m. But this is only correct for m>=1. For 0<=m<=1 the limit seems to be 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer